# onScroll only called when the OnScrollListener is set but never when you scroll on the listview?

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I have the following custom onScrollListener implementation:

```
public abstract class EndlessScrollListener implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

private static final String TAG = "EndlessScrollListener";

// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

public EndlessScrollListener() {
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
}

public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold, int startPage) {
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    this.startingPageIndex = startPage;
    this.currentPage = startPage;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount,int totalItemCount)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onScroll");
    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0) { this.loading = true; }
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        currentPage++;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<=(firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
        onLoadMore(currentPage + 1, totalItemCount);
        loading = true;
    }
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    // Don't take any action on changed
}
```

}

in my fragment containing the listview i have the following:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(2) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            loadNextPage(page);
        }
    });
```

For some reason the onScroll method is only called when the fragment is created and never actually called when I scroll. How do I fix this and why is this happening?

Comment: have u found any solution am also stucked there

Comment: I am also not getting any solution to it.

Comment: Any solution here?

Comment: same problem here.  my recyclerview is in a child fragment for a fragment's (the parent of that child) viewpager. Hm.